# Get text from EditText with it Style in android

Tags: android

I am having an editext with the text
"**This is a BOLD Text**" and
"*This is a ITALIC Text*"

if i get the text from edittext and display in textview means i am getting
"This is a BOLD Text" and
"This is a ITALIC Text"

i want to display like
"**This is a BOLD Text**" and
"*This is a ITALIC Text*"

How to acheive this

Comment: Can you show us the code please?

Comment: TextView tv;EditText et; tv.setText(et.getText().toString) and i am changing the EditText style using text Editor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leave out the `toString`:

```
TextView tv;
EditText et;

...

tv.setText(et.getText());
```

Comment: Henry:Displaying in TextView works great but pass the text using et.getText() to another activity not getting the text

Comment: @user1201450 : To pass values to next activity, you should use **et.getText().toString()**

Comment: @Sahil Mahajan Mj i want to pass the edittext value with its style if i use et.getText().toString() i can't able to get the style

Comment: @user1201450 I searched a bit but did not find anything useful. Maybe start a new question "How to pass a Spannable to another activity".

Answer (score 0):

You can use text1.setTypeface(edit1.getTypeface());
and text1.setTypeface(edit2.getTypeface());
This will help you to set the style of Textview as same of the EditText.